# Why $\min (s, t) =\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0 d u$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Why $\min (s,t) =\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0 du$?

Background of the question is:

An elementary illustration of the integral representation theorem arises from the kernel
$$
\begin{aligned}
K(s, t) & =\min (s, t) \\
& =\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0 d u
\end{aligned}
$$

defined on $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ with $x_{+} $being 0 for $x \leq 0$ and $x$ otherwise. The RKHS $\mathbb{H}(K)$ generated by this kernel consists of all functions of the form
$$
f(t)=\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0 F(u) d u=\int_0^t F(u) d u
$$
with
$$
||f||^2=\int_0^1 F^2(u) d u
$$

I don't understand why $\min (s,t) =\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0 du$? I know that When $u \leq \min(s, t)$, we have $(t-u)_+^0 = t-u$ and $(s-u)_+^0 = s-u$, so the product becomes $(t-u)(s-u)$.

For $u > \min(s, t)$, either $(t-u)_+^0$ or $(s-u)_+^0$ (or both) will be zero, so the product will be zero, and these regions do not contribute to the integral.

Therefore, the integral $\int_0^1 (t-u)_+^0 (s-u)_+^0 du$ effectively integrates the product $(t-u)(s-u)$ from $u=0$ to $u=\min(s, t)$.
But I don't know how to show that  $\min (s,t) =\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0 du$.

Comment: Just verifying the odd-looking notation...  Are you sure that the superscript $0$ is part of the "positive part" notation and is not a power, i.e., $(t-u)_+^0 = \begin{cases} 0 ,& t \leq u \\ t-u ,& t > u \end{cases}$ instead of $\left((t-u)_+\right)^0 = \begin{cases} 0 ,& t \leq u \\ 1 ,& t > u \end{cases}$?

Comment: I agree with @EricTowers ... the formula is **wrong** with the definition of $x_+^0$ in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the notation is not standard, it seems that the author means
$$
x_+^0=\begin{cases}
0,&\ x<0\\
1,&\ x\geq0
\end{cases}
$$
With this assumption, and assuming without loss of generality that $s\leq t$, \begin{align}
\int_0^1(t-u)_{+}^0(s-u)_{+}^0\, d u
&=\int_0^s1\, d u=s
\end{align}
You can see that this the intended meaning of the notation if you look at the next formula in the text, where the author writes
$$
\int_0^1(t-u)_+^0\,F(u)\,du=\int_0^tF(u)\,du. 
$$